# Stop Windows command prompt from scrolling past cursor

Tags: cmd.exe, window, console, scrolling, buffer

I’m using Windows 10 for my current project after more than a decade on macOS / Linux. `cmd` seems to have come on a bit from Windows XP days, but I’m having one particular problem.

On macOS’s Terminal if I scroll back up to check something, when I want to go back I can fling the scroll in the other direction and it will stop at the end of the current text where the cursor is. If I do the same in Command Prompt it turns out there’s thousands of lines of blank text at the bottom beyond the cursor and I need to carefully scroll back through it to get back to the cursor. Typing something will refocus to the correct line, but only if there’s a cursor; if I’m running my test suite it waits for commands without dropping back to the shell, and won’t scroll to the correct point on typing.

I’ve been through the settings and can’t see anything obvious to change. Is there any way I can change the behaviour to match macOS’s Terminal, or am I going to have to relearn my muscle memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Windows 10 build 18298 and up you can go to properties and enable the *"Disable Scroll-Forward"* checkbox

[image: Disable Scroll Forward in properties]

> ## Disable Scroll Forward:
>
> When cleared (default state), the Console can to scroll anywhere within the Console’s buffer, even below the most recent row of text displayed When checked, the Console will not allow scrolling below the last line output, similar to how most *NIX terminals work

- [New Experimental Console Features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/)
- [How to Enable or Disable Scroll Forward in Console Window in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/123428-enable-disable-scroll-forward-console-window-windows-10-a.html)
- [Disable Scroll Forward in Console in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-scroll-forward-console-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks! Changed this to be the accepted answer.

Comment: To get to this dialog box of "Command prompt properties" you have to **right click** on the top bar of the window.

Comment: @Ben there are so many ways to access that dialog: **left click** on the icon on the top left, press Alt+Space or right click **inside** the console when quick edit mode is disabled

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools`, right click it go to properties, go to `layout`, change the `Screen Buffer Size` `height` to 12 or something that will do it.

Comment: Its still possible to scroll trough the prompt after applying this setting.

Comment: it is working for me did you change the window size or the screen buffer size?

Comment: Changed to wrong setting, its working now.

Comment: So that seems to limit going back in history to 12 (or whatever) lines as well. I’m looking for a solution that lets me go far as far as I want (or at least within reason), but doesn’t have a load of blank lines past current prompt / end of text.

Comment: You could try to put it at what you think you need or alternatively you might be able to use ">" with the commands like so: "ping 8.8.8.8 -n 500 > output.txt".

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently do this, however there's an [open bug at Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/122) to fix it.